# Getting referrer in AEM segments

Tags: aem

I am trying to create segment in AEM 6.1 based on referring website. I found ootb trait called referring keywords but could not find how to get referrer. Can anyone help how to create segment based on referrer.

Thanks

Comment: Haven't done this but I imagine you could create a script based segment with the script `document.referrer` for checking the referrer.

Comment: Thanks @Abhishek. This seems to be working. Is there any way to simulate value of document.referrer variable to test for referrers like google.com or bing.com. Because this is my dev server and can't actually refer to my dev server from these search engines.

Comment: I think there is a [chrome plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/referer-control/hnkcfpcejkafcihlgbojoidoihckciin?hl=en) to do that sort of testing.